# Help with a proof regarding non-measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Please help with the following question where $|E|$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

> We say set $A⊆\Bbb{R}^n$ is a translation of set $B⊆\Bbb{R}^n$ if $A=B+z$ for some $z∈\Bbb{R}^n$. Let $E$ be a measurable set in $\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $0<|E|<+∞$. If there exists a countable sequence of disjoint sets $E_k$ such that $E=⋃E_k$ and $∀i,j$ $E_i$ is a translation of $E_j$. Show that all $E_k$s must be non-measurable sets.

I am not sure, but I have a problem with above $E_k$s and the above construction seems impossible to me.

> Let $|E_k|_e$, $|E|_e$ denote the outer measure of $E_k$ and $E$. Since it already states $E$ is measurable, $|E|_e=|E|$. Then $|E|\le\sum|E_k|_e$ due to outer measure has subadditivity. Also since outer measure is invariant to translation, so all $|E_k|_e$ are equal. $|E|>0$, then $|E_k|_e> 0$, but that gives $|E|=\sum|E_k|_e=+\infty$, contradicting with $|E|<+\infty$.

Comment: Your last line is not necessarily true. Recall that you only have $|E| {\color{red} \leq} \sum |E_k|_e$. To fix this, assume one $E_k$ to be measurable. Then all $E_k$ are measurable (why?), so that you get equality by disjointness.